# Origin of notation $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ for smooth vector fields on a smooth manifold $M$

Tags: terminology, smooth-manifolds, math-history, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with or without boundary. A **vector field** on $M$ is simply a smooth section of the projection $\pi : TM \to M$. The **space of all vector fields** on $M$ may be denoted by (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Vector_fields_on_manifolds)) $$\Gamma(TM) \qquad \mathrm{Vect}(M) \qquad \mathfrak{X}(M)$$ Whereas the first two notations are quite intuitive (one can argue about the letter $\Gamma$ for sections), the last one seems a bit off for me. I know, that sometimes notations are just get established because they are handy, like in this case short, nonetheless I quite wonder, where this notation originates from. So to state my question:

> What is the meaning behind the notation $\mathfrak{X}(M)$, i.e. fraktur $X$, for the space of smooth vector fields on a manifold $M$?

Comment: I don't thinks there's anything special in the choice of $\frak X$; it's just "handy"!  Cheers!

Comment: Maybe you also want to add the math-story tag.

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you for your opinion!

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Just added, thanks.

Comment: Some authors use the letter $X$ to refer to vector fields.